# How to get distinct values using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

Hello i got a table like this=>

```
    stateID    requestNo    reqStateID       reqStateDate
       1          1             13        03.01.2012 10:57
       2          1              3        03.01.2012 10:58
       3          2              3        03.01.2012 11:14
       4          2              3        03.01.2012 11:15
       5          1              5        03.01.2012 22:28
       6          1              7        05.01.2012 14:54
       7          3              3        05.01.2012 14:55
```

I need to get, last added(reqStateDate) unique Requests No (requestNo).
I tried something like this but it's not work..

```
    public List<ReqStates> GetRequests(int reqStateID)
    {
        return  (from rs in db.ReqStates
                          where rs.reqStateID== reqStateID
                          orderby rs.reqStateDate descending
                          select rs).Distinct().ToList();            
    }
```

if parameter (reqStateID) takes 3, I have to get 2 requests. requestNo = 2 and requestNo = 3.
Because, both of request's reqstateID is 3 and their added dates the latest.
RequestNo=1=> the last added status is 13.
This is why it(1) should not come.

I hope someone can help me, and shows an easy way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tell `Distinct` by what property it should distinct the values. The default equality comparer will be used to distinct the values if nothing is specified.

You have two options here:

1. Pass an `IEqualityComparer` to distinct.
2. Implement `IEquatable` on the `ReqStates`.

Example:

```
class ReqStatesComparer: IEqualityComparer<ReqStates>
{
  public bool Equals(ReqStates a, ReqStates b)
  {
    return a.requestNo == b.requestNo;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(ReqStates rs)
  {
    return rs.GetHashCode();
  }
}


    public List<ReqStates> GetRequests(int reqStateID)
    {
        return  (from rs in db.ReqStates
                          where rs.reqStateID== reqStateID
                          orderby rs.reqStateDate descending
                          select rs).Distinct(new ReqStatesComparer()).ToList();            
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give me a sample using IEqualityComparer.

Comment: Great understandable example, i appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what result your looking for but your doing a distinct on the whole object. So the object must be distinct across all fields.

Try below where you're just selecting a field and not the whole object.

Then modify to only use the fields you need.

Try this

```
return  (from rs in db.ReqStates
                      where rs.reqStateID== reqStateID
                      orderby rs.reqStateDate descending
                      select rs.requestNo).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I already tried that but that gives me all of requestNo's that have reqStateID==3. first condition is request added date(reqStateDate) must be the latest and then reqStateID==3.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to retrieve the latest requests by requestNo with the latest `reqStateDate` given an ID.  If this is the case, you can do:

```
public List<ReqStates> GetRequests(int reqStateID)
{
    return db.ReqStates.Where(rs => rs.reqStateID == reqStateID)
                       .GroupBy(rs => rs.requestNo)
                       .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(rs => rs.reqStateDate).First()) 
                       .ToList();            
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i get an error:"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead." replaced First() with FirstOrDefault() but this time "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details." error raised.

Comment: and the inner exception says {"Specified method is not supported."}

Comment: @user892945 Is this LINQ to SQL, or EF, or LINQ to Objects?  (The above works fine in Linq to Objects...)